# call_user_func_array() args with strings as keys to match function args names

Tags: php, function

At the moment I have something like this

```
function callFunction($method, $args) {
    if(method_exists($this, $method)) {
            call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $args);
    }
}

function myfunction ($hello, $world, $blah) {
}
```

where `$args` is an array like `[0] => 'string1', [1] => 'string2', [2] => 'string3'` which gets passed to the function in that order. However would there be a way to have the keys to the args match the functions argument names. like `['hello'] => 'string1', ['world'] => 'string2', ['blah'] => 'string3'` where they could be in any order and be matched to the correct argument name by key?

Comment: You'd need to use `ReflectionMethod::getParameters()`  for that. Not a real issue to write something for it, but do take into account this creates some overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite some overhead, but possible:

```
function callFunction($method, $args) {
    if(method_exists($this, $method)) {
         $arguments = array();
         $reflectionmethod = new ReflectionMethod($this,$method);
         foreach($reflectionmethod->getParameters() as $arg){
             if(isset($args[$arg->name])){
                 $arguments[$arg->name] = $args[$arg->name];
             } else if($arg->isDefaultValueAvailable()){
                 $arguments[$arg->name] = $arg->getDefaultValue();
             } else {
                 $arguments[$arg->name] = null;
             }
         }
         call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $arguments);
    }
}

function myfunction ($hello, $world, $blah) {
}
```

Something that is passed by reference would be iffy though. You'd probably need some more code to make that work. Long story short: PHP ain't Python :)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there would be a method for this but I figured you may have to do something like this. Good answer!

Comment: ReflectionMethod doesn't have a method getArguments. The correct one is $reflectionmethod->getParameters()  http://php.net/manual/ro/reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters.php

Comment: @DaniDudas: thanks for pointing that out (could have sworn I tested it back then, but the manual says otherwise indeed). BTW: [you can always suggest an edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work), which works a bit quicker.